# Simple builder pattern implementation for building immutable objects

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, immutability, fluent-interface

This is a builder pattern implementation to build immutable `Person` objects:

**`Person` class**

```
public final class Person {

    // All are set to final to make Person Immutable
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String surname;
    private final boolean isOccupied;

    // Constructor is private, so that only static
    // PersonBuilder can initiate the Person class instance
    private Person(PersonBuilder builder) {
        this.id = builder.getId();
        this.name = builder.getName();
        this.surname = builder.getSurname();
        this.isOccupied = builder.isOccupied();
    }

    public static class PersonBuilder {

        // Member variables of PersonBuilder are temporary storage
        // to create Immutable Person class instance
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private boolean isOccupied;

        PersonBuilder() { }

        // The only method to initiate Person class
        Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }

        // Multiple Constructors for each member variable
        public PersonBuilder id(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder surname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder setOccupied(boolean isOccupied) {
            this.isOccupied = isOccupied;
            return this;
        }

        // getters, these will be used in private constructor
        // of Person class
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public boolean isOccupied() {
            return isOccupied;
        }
    }

    // getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public boolean isOccupied() {
        return isOccupied;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return String.format(
                "Id:\t\t%d\nName:\t\t%s\nSurname:\t%s\nIsOccupied:\t%s\n"
                , id, name, surname, isOccupied);
    }

}
```

**`Person` demo**

```
public class PersonDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // PersonBuilder instance
        Person.PersonBuilder builder = new Person.PersonBuilder();

        // builder builds the instance
        builder.name("Levent").surname("Divilioglu").id(666).setOccupied(true);

        // Immutable Person object is initiated with build() method
        Person person = builder.build();

        System.out.println(person);
    }

}
```

**Demo output**

> ```
> Id:           666
> Name:     Levent
> Surname:  Divilioglu
> IsOccupied:   true
> ```

I did write this implementation to learn the GoF builder pattern. Immutability is important for thread-safety, thus set the class and it's members final. I also set the Person constructor private to guarantee that it is only instantiated with inner class method, and only once. On each `build()` method, a new unique `Person` instance will be created.

I'm aware that builder patter is used for classes that have a lot of many member variables but I did only used 4 member variables for the simplicity.

Comment: The builder object maintains a state. If you call **`build()`** several times in a row, you will create as much identical persons. Is that your intention?

Comment: It is a builder pattern structure to use flexible dot notation however each instance of Person will be unique, thus immutable. If build() called several times inside a Person constructor, each Person object will be immutable and unique, that was my intention. And the Person objects thread-safe as all member variables are final, are settable only for once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, very good job.

Now I will point out a few things that I think can be improved on.

**Code Duplication**

You have copied over all the `private` fields from `Person` to the `Builder`, which is necessary when the fields are declared `final`. As coderodde pointed out, using a `final` declaration is not necessary here when the fields are private and there are no setters.

Now that the fields are no longer declared final, it is possible to hold an unfinished version of your `Person` object in your builder. Now all the fields from `Person` no longer need to be copied over.

This also prevents the need for the getter methods on your `Builder` and the weird constructor of `Person` that takes a `Builder` as a parameter. The `Person` class should not be initializing itself via the state of the `Builder` object. The `Builder` should be building the `Person`, hence the name of the pattern.

**Excessive commenting**

You use comments a lot, even at places where they aren't needed and are generally just noisy. For example:

```
// getters
```

and

```
// getters, these will be used in private constructor
// of Person class`.
```

The first one is simply redundant, since all the methods below it are called `get...`, clearly indicating a getter function. The second one also provides little useful information. Note that generally, someone will read a code file from top to bottom, unless they might be looking for the details on a specific method. This would mean that they have already scrolled past your constructor and seen the getters being used there.

But there is a bigger point I want to make here with regards to the comments. In general, using comments to express what your code does, means that you have failed to express yourself in code, which can document itself when names are chosen carefully.

Coming back to the second comment I mentioned. You probably wrote that because you felt that you had to explain yourself for having public getters on your `Builder` class. When placing a comment like this, take a step back and ask yourself why you placed that comment and if your code would still seem logical without it. If your code seems weird without the comment, which I think public getters on a `Builder` class do, then you need to fix that issue instead of commenting about why you did it.

Now by moving the initialization of the `Person` to the `Builder` class where it belongs, as mentioned above, the `Builder` no longer needs these methods and the comment can be removed.

The same goes for the comment about the temporary member variables, which can now be removed as the `Builder` simply holds an instance of the `Person` class, which makes perfect sense on its own.

I went on a bit of a rant about comments, but I hope you can see what I mean.

**Naming**

Overall, job well done with the naming. A few remarks though:

- I'd rename `PersonBuilder` to `Builder`. It's an inner class of `Person` so there really is no need for it. `Person.Builder` is perfectly fine.
- I'd also rename the individual building methods for `id`, `name`, `surname` and `isOccupied` to `setId`, `setName`, `setSurname` and `setOccupied`, since they are all effectively setters.

**Reworked Code**

When incorporating these points into your code, it should look a little something like this.

```
public final class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private boolean isOccupied;

    private Person() {}

    public static class Builder {
        private Person personToBuild;

        Builder() {
            personToBuild = new Person();
        }

        Person build() {
            Person builtPerson = personToBuild;
            personToBuild = new Person();

            return builtPerson;
        }

        public Builder setId(int id) {
            this.personToBuild.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setName(String name) {
            this.personToBuild.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setSurname(String surname) {
            this.personToBuild.surname = surname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOccupied(boolean isOccupied) {
            this.personToBuild.isOccupied = isOccupied;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public boolean isOccupied() {
        return isOccupied;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return String.format(
                "Id:\t\t%d\nName:\t\t%s\nSurname:\t%s\nIsOccupied:\t%s\n"
                , id, name, surname, isOccupied);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with many of your points concerning comments, but I must respectfully disagree with your comment that explaining code function in a comment means the coding is done poorly.  Generally speaking, programmers come with different levels of experience, knowledge, and expertise.  Knowed programmers might not need the documentation to understand the code's function, but novice programmers very well may.

Comment: @Thijs Riezebeek : Thanks for your useful comments and your demo code. I'll check out internet and some books in order to check your code with other sources but I must point that I've found it very useful. Important thing is to know where to use which approach and I want to be aware of every approaches. I also agree that commenting is important to guide&notify other programmers and for documentation considerations. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the thought process behind `Builder.build()`? Why are you creating a new `Person` reference and re-instantiating `personToBuild`, instead of simply returning `personToBuild`? Is it just for clarity of semantic meaning?

Comment: @Eric Guan, the reason for that is to reset the builder. Once you call the `build()` method, it is common practice to reset the state of the builder so it can be reused.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your builder by removing the **`final`** specifiers from the fields of **`Person`**. Don't worry, unless you add setters for the person type, it is effectively immutable.

**`toString()`** is not usually used as a method for printing human-readable output, but rather used as an aid in debugging.

I had this in mind:

```
public final class Person {

    // The class has no setters, so it's effectively immutable. We need a 
    // possibility of setting to these fields so that we can construct them in 
    // the builder.
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private boolean isOccupied;

    // Hide the constructor from the user.
    private Person() {}

    public static final class Builder {

        private Person person;

        // Initialize state.
        private Builder(final Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }

        // Start building a person.
        public static Builder build() {
            return new Builder(new Person());
        }

        public Builder id(final int id) {
            this.person.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder name(final String name) {
            this.person.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder surname(final String surname) {
            this.person.surname = surname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder occupied(final boolean isOccupied) {
            this.person.isOccupied = isOccupied;
            return this;
        }

        // End construction and return a unique person object.
        public Person get() {
            final Person ret = new Person();
            ret.id         = person.id;
            ret.name       = person.name;
            ret.surname    = person.surname;
            ret.isOccupied = person.isOccupied;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    // getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public boolean isOccupied() {
        return isOccupied;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return String.format("[id: %d, name: %s, surname: %s, occupied: %b]",
                             id, 
                             processNull(name),
                             processNull(surname),
                             isOccupied);
    }

    private static String processNull(final String str) {
        return str == null ? "null" : "\"" + str + "\"";
    }
}

public class PersonDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = Person.Builder
                               .build()
                               .name("Funky")
                               .surname("Funk")
                               .id(1337)
                               .occupied(true)
                               .get();

        Person person2 = Person.Builder
                               .build()
                               .name("Alice")
                               .id(123)
                               .get();

        System.out.println(person1);
        System.out.println(person2);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for toString() comment, I agree but why not use final keyword? If I used this code in a big project with a team, I would prefer anyone to ask himself/herself that why a final keyword is used so that he/she could foresee that it's used for the sake of object state consistency. I also wonder that if is there any trade-off for using and not using final keyword.

Comment: You seem to have made an interesting distinction between human-readable output and a debugging aid... so debugging aids don't have to be readable by humans? :)

Comment: Of course it has. However, aiding debugging **`toString`** - in my opinion - should return all the stuff in one line of text.

Comment: Removing final from the Person fields does mean that some visibility guarantees are lost, from a multi threading point of view.

Comment: @bowmore Can you tell & explain a little bit more about usage of final for the point of thread-safety ?

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu "Final fields can’t be modified (although the objects they refer to can be modified if they are mutable), but they also
have special semantics under the Java Memory Model." More specifically, an object with only final fields can be safely published and shared, through any mechanism. Without the final modifiers the same Object must be safely published (but can be shared without further synchronization). So omitting final on its fields would make Person, in this question, an object we should make sure to publish safely. (see Java Concurrency in Practice for a full explanation)

Comment: @bowmore Then it seems a good idea to use final keyword for mutable objects, isn't it? Especially if we want the references not to be updated, we should remove the getters and use final keyword with the reference fields in order to remove the visibility for thread-safety? Please correct me If I'm on the wrong direction.

Comment: A mutable object's fields cannot all be final. If you define a class whose instances will be shared across threads, then making it immutable and have final fields is the best option (if that is possible). But even a mutable object can be shared between threads, yet you'll need explicit synchronization to pull that off. Some objects are not meant to be shared across threads, and all of this is not even a concern. Encapsulation is always a good design choice; if you can do without an accessor, leave it out. If you can make a field final, make it final.

Comment: That's amazing. You entirely eliminated the `new` keyword, but isn't this like you have a builder to create a `Builder` ? Moreover, I really like the idea of @Thijs Riezebeek to re-use the Builder instance, any thoughts on that ?

Answer (score 4):

If you would use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org), you can get the same classes with less code:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    String surname;
    boolean isOccupied
}
```

In Value types, all fields are private and final by default, and the class is also final. Getters, `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` are also generated.

The Builder annotation will generate a private all-args constructor, a nested builder class `PersonBuilder`, and a `public static PersonBuilder builder()` in Person.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Answer (score 3):

Several people are recommending to remove the final keyword from the private fields. I would strongly recommend against doing that. The whole point of the final keyword is to prevent accidental re-assignments to these fields from other methods in the class (private and public). So, if a Person is immutable, then all the fields in Person should be marked final. I actually have my IDE configured to automatically mark fields private on save. Immutability is a good thing to have unless you really want mutable state.

Your builder does not need getters; remove them. I would not inject the builder into the Person constructor and keep the business of building in the builder. Instead inject the individual fields from the build method. This way, you can make the Person constructor public and use it without the builder as well and you stick to the principle that constructors should not do work (other than assigning arguments).

Now regarding the getters on Person; if your fields are final, you might as well make them public and skip adding getter methods. Why type `myobject.getFoo()` when you can just type `myobject.foo`? The only reason to have getters at all is that is if you are depending on frameworks that still expect javabeans style getters with the naming conventions and verbose sillyness that comes with that. If that's not the case, don't add them.

Some other things I would tweak are moving the Builder.build() method to `public static Builder Person.person(){...}`. This will simplify the business of creating a Person builder and you won't need to type `Person.Builder.build()` which looks a bit ugly to me.

Comment: After years, have seen this comment. If I was going to write the same code now, definitely agree and apply what you have written. I don't know why I have written getters inside the builder :)

Comment: I moved on and now use Kotlin and data classes. Kotlin has no need for builders as it has default immutable, final vals for parameters, and a few other nice things. With Java, you  now have records but they are still mutable by default. And people also use lombok of course, which generates all this cruft for you. Never was a big fan of that but it's a valid option.

Comment: For reference, this is all you need in Kotlin. Immutable, minimal, etc. And you get usable toString, hashCode, equals, etc.

```kotlin
data class Person(val id: Long, val name: String, val surName: String?=null, val isOccupied: Boolean = false)

val p1=Person(1,"Alice")
val p2=Person(2,"Bob", "Alison",true)
```